# How to map domain to Amazon EC2 instance without using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i want to map domain to Amazon EC2 instance without using Route 53
i have installed bitnami wordpress 
Linux/Unix, Ubuntu 16.04 | 64-bit Amazon Machine Image (AMI)
plz i need detailed steps I am beginner

Answer (score 0):

You just create an A record in your preferred dns provider and set it to the public ip of your instance. Make sure the security group allows port 80/443 for http/https traffic to the instance.